# trigger an event from class library to wpf

Tags: event-handling, class-library

I have create a class library to handle to do payments by payment terminal. 
I want to trigger an event to my wpf application, when the payment finish.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue by using the delegates.

In Class library
1. Declare a delegate in classlibrary

```
  public delegate void GetResponseDelegate(bool isSuccess);
```

1. Declare a delegate event in the class which you used to get the result

   public event GetResponseDelegate responseEvent;
2. Call the delegate event within the method where you can get result

   bool myResult=true;
      if(responseEvent!=null)
      {
       responseEvent(myResult);
      }

In wpf application
1. creating a object to the class library class where you declare the delegate event

```
 MyLib.Class1 c1=new MyLib.Class1();
```

1. initialize the delegate event

   c1.responseEvent+=new MyLib.GetResponseDelegate(GetResponseMethod);

3.Get your response inside the delegate event method

```
 void GetResponseMethod(bool isSuccess)
  {
    //do your actions with the result
  }
```